# HTML Table - max-width not working on td descendants

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have table with `width: 100%` and an element in that table with `width: 40em; max-width: 100%`, but the element is still stretching the table when the browser window gets too small.

I want this element to be a fixed width but not be larger than the container if the container gets too small. If there's not enough room for the fixed width, `max-width: 100%` should make it smaller to fit the available space. This works outside of a table.

Note that the `max-width` is not on the table itself. It is actually on an `<input>` element, although the code I've linked includes a separate table with the same problem on a `<span>` element. It also includes an `<input>` field outside of the table which behaves correctly.

[link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vekSW/12/)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should use [`table-layout: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) for the table element to get the `max-width` properties of `<td>`'s descendants to work.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout):

> The `table-layout` CSS property defines the algorithm to be used to
>   layout the table cells, rows, and columns.
>
> **fixed** value:
>   Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in
>   subsequent rows do not affect column widths.

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/vekSW/22/)**.

Comment: this is really a weird behavior, why would they make table elements so special?

Answer (score 3):

if you put it on the element, the element gets stretched to `max-width: 100%`.

If you want fixed width, use `width: 40px` (instead of %, percentages are used in liquid layouts)

Comment: ...you changed the answer completely rendering my previous comment nonsense. Now it just sounds like you both don't understand `max-width` or what I'm trying to do.

Comment: oh ok. what is it that you want to achieve, fixed layouts need to have px specified.

Comment: It's not for a page layout. The page layout itself allows the table width to be fluid (100%). The element in the table is an input field which should display at its native width, but if there isn't enough room it should shrink to fit the available space.

Comment: ok, you need to do put the width of the input field like, say `width: 20%;` i.e. a percentage in comparison to the table/container. so whenever the container gets smaller, the input field gets smaller with it.